# build amplify timeout auth/userPoolGroups

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, aws-code-deploy, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

i have setup CI/CD. when i deploying then timeout and deploy failed.
this is my log.

```
2022-10-11T02:12:10.104Z [WARNING]: - Uploading files.
2022-10-11T02:12:17.473Z [WARNING]: - Uploading files.
2022-10-11T02:12:19.565Z [INFO]: [33mNote: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory[39m
2022-10-11T02:12:21.688Z [WARNING]: - Initializing your environment: prod
2022-10-11T02:12:30.644Z [WARNING]: - Building resource auth/userPoolGroups
```

it stoped on Building resource auth/userPoolGroups state.

Comment: There is no error here. Only some warnings.

Comment: this is only i receive from log of amplify state build. My env can not deploy

Comment: when you vote -1 for me, i think you need read all content my question

Comment: it stoped on Building resource auth/userPoolGroups state and failed by timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You should change version amplify in your setting build and redeploy again.
Sometime version latest not compatible with your project.
I try change version to 7.6.14 and that work.

Comment: yeah, thank you. i try change version to 7.4.16 and this work for me.